# How to round 0.01 to 0.01 in C#

Tags: c#, math

I am using Math.Round(0.01,3) in order to round the number to 3 decimal points.

However, the 0 on the right is not showing up.

This is done using a loop so some numbers can be longer. but i need this to work for numbers that only have 2 decimals. 
Please provide a method to add the 0 to the right.

Comment: "how to round 0.01 to 0.01"...these two numbers are identical. Check that you've asked your question correctly.

Comment: You're not after rounding the number, you don't want to change the precision. May be you should be using `0.01.ToString("N3")` for display purposes

Comment: `0.01` and `0.010` are the same thing. This sounds more like an issue with how you're formatting your output.

Comment: "I am using Math.Round(0.01,3) in order to round the number to 3 decimal points" makes no sense...the number only has 2 decimal points to begin with. Rounding is the process of making the number have _less_ decimal points (i.e. be slightly less accurate). What would be the point of adding an extra 0 here? It conveys nothing useful. If you want to **display** the number with 3 decimal points for some (strange) reason then that is a formatting procedure which you should do in your GUI layer, not a mathematical rounding operation on the raw data.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the 0 on the right is not showing up.

When working with `int`/`float`/`double`/... you are working with **mathematical** values. Mathematically, `0.010 == 0.01`. Both values represent the same numerical value.

What you're interested in is the **formatting** of your data. These operations are done on a `string` representation of your data.

For strings, `"0.01" != "0.010"` since the two values are different sequences of characters.

What you want to do is convert your mathematical value into a string which follows a specific format. In the case of needing to always display three decimals, the `N3` format applies. In other words:

```
float myValue = 0.01f;
string myFormattedValue = myValue.ToString("N3");

Console.WriteLine(myValue);            // 0.01
Console.WriteLine(myFormattedValue);   // 0.010
```

[Fiddle code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UzAJ9a)

But `myFormattedValue` is a `string` and you can't use it for calculations anymore (unless you re-convert it to a mathematical value).